Oracle Apex date validation error when passing through a proc
When I pass the below in it works BUT if I place the date_column in there I get an error.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
-- Works fine 
DECLARE
  PARAMS SCHEDULER_ARGS := SCHEDULER_ARGS(BATCH_RUN_NO    => :P6_ANNIV_DATE,
                                          BATCH_DETAIL_NO => :P6_BATCH_DETAIL_NO,
                                          ANNIV_DATE      =>  to_date('01-12-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),
                                          POLICY_NO       => :P6_POLICY_NO,
                                          NO_OF_THREADS   => :P6_NO_OF_THREADS,
                                          THREAD_NO       => :P6_THREAD_NO,
                                          ENTITY_NO       => :P6_ENTITY_NO,
                                          PROCESS_NO      => :P6_PROCESS_NO,
                                          ANNIV_RECALC    => :P6_ANNIV_RECALC,
                                          PROC_DESCR      => :P6_PROC_DESCR,
                                          OVERRIDE_DATE   => :P6_OVERRIDE_DATE);
BEGIN
  l_pkg_scheduler_utility.run_batch_threads(params => params);
END;

-- Error
DECLARE
  PARAMS SCHEDULER_ARGS := SCHEDULER_ARGS(BATCH_RUN_NO    => :P6_ANNIV_DATE,
                                          BATCH_DETAIL_NO => :P6_BATCH_DETAIL_NO,
                                          ANNIV_DATE      =>  to_char(to_date(:P6_ANN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
                                          POLICY_NO       => :P6_POLICY_NO,
                                          NO_OF_THREADS   => :P6_NO_OF_THREADS,
                                          THREAD_NO       => :P6_THREAD_NO,
                                          ENTITY_NO       => :P6_ENTITY_NO,
                                          PROCESS_NO      => :P6_PROCESS_NO,
                                          ANNIV_RECALC    => :P6_ANNIV_RECALC,
                                          PROC_DESCR      => :P6_PROC_DESCR,
                                          OVERRIDE_DATE   => :P6_OVERRIDE_DATE);
BEGIN
  l_pkg_scheduler_utility.run_batch_threads(params => params);
END;


Why are you converting a string to a date and then back to a string with the same format mask?  If anniv_date is supposed to be a date, why not pass in a date?  Are you sure :P6_ANN_DATE is a string in the format DD-MM-YYYY?  My guess would be that if you debugged it that the format mask is different.

The session state is in the DD-MM-YYYY format

You updated your example so the hard-coded version is passing in a date and the one you want is passing in a string.  Assuming anniv_date is a date, both should be passing in a date not a string.  If anniv_date is a date, you are still converting :P6_ANN_DATE to a date, then to a string, and then implicitly back to a date.

In APEX all page items are treated as strings so any pl/sql that has parameters of type DATE  will do an implicit conversion. If the datatype of ANNIV_DATE is DATE then the following code is wrong:
ANNIV_DATE      =>  to_char(to_date(:P6_ANN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),


It converts a page item (that is a string CHAR datatype, NOT a date datatype) to a date and then back to a string... as an argument for a DATE parameter. So the pl/sql engine will then do an implicit TO_DATE again... That is 3 conversions.
Just put
ANNIV_DATE      =>  to_date(:P6_ANN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),


If the above did not help, then do the following 2 things:

instrument your code:

DECLARE
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_ANNIV_DATE: %0',:P6_ANNIV_DATE);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_BATCH_DETAIL_NO: %0',:P6_BATCH_DETAIL_NO);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_ANN_DATE: %0',:P6_ANN_DATE);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_POLICY_NO: %0',:P6_POLICY_NO);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_NO_OF_THREADS: %0',:P6_NO_OF_THREADS);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_THREAD_NO: %0',:P6_THREAD_NO);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_ENTITY_NO: %0',:P6_ENTITY_NO);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_PROCESS_NO: %0',:P6_PROCESS_NO);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_ANNIV_RECALC: %0',:P6_ANNIV_RECALC);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_PROC_DESCR: %0',:P6_PROC_DESCR);
  APEX_DEBUG.INFO (p_message => 'SO Debug P6_OVERRIDE_DATE: %0',:P6_OVERRIDE_DATE);  PARAMS SCHEDULER_ARGS := SCHEDULER_ARGS(BATCH_RUN_NO    => :P6_ANNIV_DATE,
... (rest of your code)


Run the page in debug, it will error out just like it did before but the debug entries will show the details (search for the string "SO Debug"). Add the results to your question.

Provide the specification for the object type SCHEDULER_ARGS


The date must be chosen from the application.

I have updated the example

Updated my question, it should guide you in the right direction. If it does not, then do the 2 things I asked for and add the results to your question.

I see I missed that P6_ANN_DATE page item in the debug - updated that. I'm aware that the date is chosen in the application

This worked the next morning in APEX after a bounce but now it errors on the DB side ANNIV_DATE      =>  to_date(:P6_ANN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'). I'll have to dig deeper
